# django и mssql как вывести на страницу результат выборки

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь понять и разобраться как вообще все это работает но пока безуспешно.
Единственное, что у меня получилось это вывести одну строчку из выборки.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import pyodbc

def contact(request):
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=******;DATABASE=******;UID=*******;PWD=********')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE NUM IN(23546,22325)")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    context = {
        'NUM':str(row.NUM),
        'NAME':str(row.NAME)
        }
    return render(request,"hj/basic.html",context)
```

basic.html

```
 {% extends "hj/wrapp.html" %}
         {% block content %}
                 {{NUM}}{{NAME}}
         {% endblock %}
```

Но "что-то" мне подсказывает, что это не совсем правильное решение.

Подскажите как сделать правильно и вывести результат выборки на страницу?

Comment: Вы не знаете про ORM в Django и поэтому таким способом делаете?

Comment: @AlTheOne Не могу разобраться как сделать правильно, потому и спрашиваю. Если вы обладаете знаниями которые могут решить данный вопрос, я с удовольствием вас выслушаю.

Comment: @idrees всеми нужными знаниями обладают любые учебники по Django. Такое чувство, будто вы до глав с ORM просто не дочитали

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import pyodbc

def contact(request):
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=******;DATABASE=******;UID=*******;PWD=********')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE NUM IN(23546,22325)")
    rows = []
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        rows.append({
            'num': str(row.NUM),
            'name': str(row.NAME)
        })        
    ctx['rows'] = rows
    return render(request, "hj/basic.html", ctx)
```

basic.html

```html
{% extends "hj/wrapp.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for row in rows %}
        {{ row.num }}, {{ row.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```